# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, pygame

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow so I apologize in advance if my question is too vague or if not enough information is provided.

Basically the problem I am having is that my code will not run due to a TypeError.

Here is the exact message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "C:\pygamehelper.py", line 62, in mainLoop
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 54, in draw
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

So I think that the error is occurring due to the tuple associated with pos being converted to a vector using the vec2d method, and then being passed as an argument (as a float) to the draw.circle method in line 54, where an int is being expected. This is how it was done in the tutorial that I am following however, and his code is identical and executed without problems.

Could it possibly be due to him using a different version of Python, or PyGame, or is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
from pygamehelper import *
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *
from vec2d import *
from math import e, pi, cos, sin, sqrt
from random import uniform

class Agents:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = vec2d(0, 0)
        self.target = vec2d(0, 0)

class Starter(PygameHelper):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w, self.h = 800, 600
        PygameHelper.__init__(self, size=(self.w, self.h), fill=((255,255,255)))

        self.agents = []

        for i in range(10):
            a = Agents()
            a.pos = vec2d(uniform(0, self.w), uniform(0, self.h))
            a.target = vec2d(uniform(0, self.w), uniform(0, self.h))
            self.agents.append(a)

    def update(self):

        for a in self.agents:

            dir = a.target - a.pos
            dir.length = 5
            a.pos = a.pos + dir

    def keyUp(self, key):
        pass

    def mouseUp(self, button, pos):

        for a in self.agents:
            a.target = vec2d(pos)

    def mouseMotion(self, buttons, pos, rel):
        pass

    def draw(self):

        # clear the screen 40 times / sec so that only 1 char and target
        # present on screen at a time
        self.screen.fill((255,255,255))


        for a in self.agents:
            # character
            pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (200, 200, 255), a.pos, 10)
            # black character outline
            pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (0, 0, 0), a.pos, 11, 1)
            # target
            pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (200, 0, 0), a.target, 20, 1)

s = Starter()
s.mainLoop(40)
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.uniform(a,b)` returns a float. use `int(random.uniform(a,b))` for an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your tuiototouch.py on line 92 is passing a float argument (self.x_mouse). Uinput expects only integers.

I think that the int-conversion could be done under the hood in suinput. So perhaps suinput should make sure that ev_value is integer before it passes it to the uinput-system.

So there are two possible solutions. I could either

- document the integer requirement for uinput.Device.emit()

or

- allow any numerical type and typecast it to integer in suinput

I'm not sure right away which is better, I'll think about it for a while.

Meanwhile, I think you can fix this by typecasting self.x_mouse to int in tuiototouch.py: int(self.x_mouse).